# How to convert smartimageview to bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I am using SmartImageView to load my images from my own database .

```
myImage = (SmartImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    myImage.setImageUrl("http://172.22.75.224/droidlogin/zonea.JPG");
```

and i would need to convert this myimage to bitmap so as to draw over it using canvas.

currently i use

```
 Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)myImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

but it keeps giving me a **null** which means that it didn't conver to bitmap.

Hope someone could assist me please!

Answer (score 0):

This is a great method of converting resource images into Android Bitmaps.

```
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.large_icon);
notBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
```

hope it will work for you ...

Comment: hi my image is inside my server . and im using smartimageview to load it into my app. But i want to draw over it now. using decode resource needs the image to be in my file.

Comment: you can use Canvas class. Canvas class will allow you to draw decoded image.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you as well.

But you try to be smart to convert this according to your problem.

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,it may help you

InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);